# Unity Drag and Drop

Tags: c#, unity3d, canvas, drag-n-drop

Есть два объекта Inventory и Field, дочерние для одного канваса. Оба объекта содержат компонент GridLayoutGroup. Задача перетащить объект из Inventory в Field. Использую интерфейсы IDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IEndDragHandler для первого и IDropHandler для второго. Все работает, объект перетаскивается и ложится в нужную ячейку, но во время перетаскивания, когда объект покидает пределы Inventory, он пропадает из виду(точнее остается в области Inventory), и появляется только когда ложится в ячейку Field. Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы объект был виден на всем пути перетаскивания. Буду признателен за любые примеры. Заранее спасибо)

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: _Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе._

Comment: Ну так поменяй родителя перетаскиваемого на канвас вовремя процесса.